# MYSQL Grouping and Having Count

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, grouping, having

I have 4 tables: tblnames, tblcountry and  tblcountry_link, tblgender.

tblcountry_link joins the names and country table together as names can have multiple countries.

tblnames:

NameID | Name | GenderID

1. Arthur  2
2. Aimee   1
3. Aubrey   1
4. Aubrey   2

tblcountry

CountryID | Country     | Nationality

1. Afghanistan    Afghan
2. Argentina      Argentinian

tblcountry_link

NameID  | CountryID

1. 1     |       1
2. 1     |       2
3. 2      |      1

tblgender

GenderID  |   Gender

1. 1      |       Female
2. 2       |      Male

I want a list of Countries and the count of the Unisex names for each country or nationality with a starting letter of my choice - so for the Letter A;

1. Afghanistan (3)
2. Argentina (5)...

I know how to find a list of names which are unisex by using Count and Having on the 'Name' column and Grouping by the nationality.

```
    {SELECT co.Nationality, COUNT( * ) 
    FROM (
    SELECT n.Name, COUNT( n.Name ) AS Countname, SUBSTR( Name, 1, 1 ) AS firstletter, g.Gender, cl.CountryID, c.Country, c.Nationality
    FROM tblnames AS n
    INNER JOIN tblgender AS g ON n.GenderID = g.GenderID
    INNER JOIN tblcountry_link AS cl ON cl.NameID = n.NameID
    INNER JOIN tblcountry AS c ON cl.CountryID = c.CountryID
    WHERE n.name LIKE CONCAT(  'A',  '%' ) 
    AND c.Nationality =  'Afghan'
    GROUP BY n.Name
    HAVING Countname >1
    ) AS co
```

This gives me the result Afghan (3)

However if I remove the Afghan part of the Where clause the results are incorrect. I have attempted various adjustments to this query to get what I want but the results never look correct.

I can also get each country or nationality for both genders (or indeed Male or Female if I add this to the Where clause).

```
    {SELECT cl.CountryID, c.Country, COUNT( n.Name ) AS Countname
    FROM tblnames AS n
    INNER JOIN tblcountry_link AS cl ON cl.NameID = n.NameID
    INNER JOIN tblcountry AS c ON cl.CountryID = c.CountryID
    WHERE n.name LIKE CONCAT( 'A', '%' ) 
    GROUP BY c.Country}
```

CountryID | Country | Countname

1. AF | Afghanistan | 624
2. AR | Argentina | 28
3. AM | Armenia | 5...

However, I am struggling to list the count of unisex names by Nationality.

I have tried combining the Having clause in the first example to the latter but this doesn't work. 
I have tried joining 2 sub queries of Male and Female where the Name matches but I couldn't get that to group and count correctly. 
I have also tried a derived table using the 1st example but I can only use 1 column and this has 2.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Let me know if it works.

```
SELECT M.Country, MaleCount, FemaleCount FROM 
(SELECT c.country, COUNT( n.Name ) AS MaleCount
    FROM tblnames AS n
    INNER JOIN tblcountry_link AS cl ON cl.NameID = n.NameID
    INNER JOIN tblcountry AS c ON cl.CountryID = c.CountryID
    WHERE n.name LIKE 'A%'
    AND GenderID = 2
    GROUP BY c.Country) AS M,
(SELECT c.country, COUNT( n.Name ) AS FemaleCount
        FROM tblnames AS n
        INNER JOIN tblcountry_link AS cl ON cl.NameID = n.NameID
        INNER JOIN tblcountry AS c ON cl.CountryID = c.CountryID
        WHERE n.name LIKE 'A%'
        AND GenderID = 1
        GROUP BY c.Country) AS F  
WHERE M.country = F.country
```

If i did it right you should have result set with country, number of males and number of females where the name starts with A. There is probably a better way. I'll edit if i think of a better way.

Comment: This works but it isn't what I want. I need the count column to only count those names that are both male and female - thus unisex - grouped by country.

Comment: Okay. I think i get it now. I'll edit my post in a few hours with a solution. If one hasn't been posted yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had another go at using a derived table. I had a read of this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/). It's TSQL but the same structure applies. I think I have got the solution below.

```
    SELECT a1.Country, COUNT(a1.Name) as NameCount FROM (
    SELECT cl.CountryID, c.Country, n.Name, COUNT( n.Name ) AS Countname
    FROM tblnames AS n
    INNER JOIN tblgender AS g ON n.GenderID = g.GenderID
    INNER JOIN tblcountry_link AS cl ON cl.NameID = n.NameID
    INNER JOIN tblcountry AS c ON cl.CountryID = c.CountryID
    WHERE n.name LIKE CONCAT( 'A', '%' ) 
    GROUP BY c.Nationality, n.Name
    HAVING Countname >1
    ORDER BY n.Name) as a1
    Group BY a1.Country
```

This gives me the results:

Country   |   NameCount

1. Afghanistan  |  3
2. Austria  |  2
3. China | 1...

Comment: Nice. I was thinking of the same thing. Sorry i miss understood your question initially. One thing i would probably change is the concat function. I would do it as 'A%' instead of concat.